# Updating an object vs updating an object's property in the state

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Is it better to update the property of an object in the state? or just replace the whole object in the state?

i.e for e.g

```
state.theObject.property = value or
state.theObject = newObject
```

Comment: generally, replace. But using [Vue.set](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) is always recommended

Comment: @JacobGoh oh ok. I have employed some "getters" and "setters" for the job though....would that suffice?